# How to search for files ending/starting/containing a certain letter in terminal?

Tags: linux, shell, ls

I have been looking all over the internet to help me with this. I want to list all files that start/end/contain a certain letter but the results I found on the internet do not seem to work for me. I need to use the ls command for this (assignment).

I tried this code from another question:

```
ls abc*   # list all files starting with abc---
ls *abc*  # list all files containing --abc--
ls *abc   # list all files ending with --abc
```

but when ever I try any of those it comes back with "ls: cannot access '*abc': No such file or directory"

Comment: I already know that, in fact the bit of code I mentioned was from that post. If you read my question you will see what was suggested there did not work for me and that I was looking for another way to find files using ls. There was one other method on those links you suggested (which I already looked at) and it only answered half my question. It did not tell how to search for something being at the end or containing it.

Comment: For a community that is supposed to help someone I am getting downvotted a lot for asking a question...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use [`find`](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man1/find.1.html) for finding files:

```
find /path/to/folder -maxdepth 1 -type f -name 'abc*'
```

This will give you all regular filenames within `/path/to/folder` which start with `abc`.

Comment: This works perfectly thank you, but what does the -type and -maxdepth do? Also do you know how to do this using "ls" command as that is part of our assignment?

Comment: There is no other way than how you showed already with `ls`. I guess the assignment silently assumes that those files are present, which is common for such kind of assignments. About the options to `find`, check `man find` (which I extra linked for you)

Comment: Do you know how I can get it to work? It seems to work perfectly find for pretty much every other user I have seen using it. If I can not get it working then it should be fine, I will just email my TA.